# KOTLIN: TelephonyManager allcellinfo return empty object in background

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager

I'm currently working on an Android app where I need to collect nearly cell info in the background using the library TelephonyManager. To achieve this, I've implemented a foreground service, including requesting all necessary permissions and displaying a persistent notification.

However, despite implementing the foreground service, when attempting to access to the data using "TelephonyManager.AllCellInfo", I'm consistently getting an empty object returned, but only when the app is in background.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide insights into why the library might be returning empty data in a foreground service on Android 13?

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!